# как в datatables задать заголовки?

Tags: javascript, datatable

собственно если указать

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Наименование</th>
        <th>еще наименование</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
```

то все работает, но как задать названия столбцов в js?

пробовал что-то такое

```
"columns": [
  { "data": "doc_id", "header": "1111"},
  { "data": "doc_name"}
]
```

не помогает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оказывается все просто, нужно в `colums` указать `title`

```
"columns": [
  { "data": "doc_id", "title": "id записи"},
  { "data": "doc_name", "title": "второй заголовок"}
]
```